# Excel, summarising most recent data in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables. I want a summary somehow to update automatically.
Table A has a history of transactions:

**Transactions**

Date|Product|Location

X1  |Y1     |Z1

Xn  |Yn     |Zn

**Summary**

Product|Current Location

Y1     |Za

Y2     |Zb

So it's sort of a: Get current Location of Product Y1 and put it in summary table.

If there was a formula which did this, it would make me so happy. I have too many uses for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **array formulas**, for example:

In the summary, the first column will have the product (Y1, Y2)
The second column will have the array formula for the latest date:

```
{=MAX(IF(B:B=I6,C:C))}
```

Where Column B is the product data, and column C is the location data, and I6 has the product cell in the summary

The third column of your summary will have a vlookup, looking up the location based on the date and product:

```
{=VLOOKUP(J6,IF(B:B=I6,A:C),3,FALSE)}
```

Where J6 is the Date that was found by formula 1

**Remember, to write an array formula, press Control+Shift+Enter when finishing the formula.**